# Как сделать чтобы бот из списка рандомно выбирал слово и отправлял его? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот например, у меня есть спиок слов и бот командой будет выбирать из этого списка слово и отправлять его в канал. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную функцию выполняет модуль random у которого есть метод choice. Он выбирает случайное значение из переданного ему списка

```
import random

words_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]

random_word = random.choice(words_list)

print(random_word)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]